# My Render is stuck at 0%

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Right now I'm trying to render an animation, but whenever i try to go to render it just stays at 0%. I've already tried render layers but that didn't help. I've been trying to fix this for the past 2 days and its driving me insane. (Also i noticed i forgot to enable render layers and it doesnt help). FIXED

Anyways here's my render settings if needed: [blender render images in google drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oZRy0zg1QofEODL2qYBzpVTDFtoWhC0d?usp=sharing)

Blender file: [blender file 1.69GB](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15XoB8lXhaOZtZI2uv5bibqSnusb-3m2P/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: at first i would reduce your samples....to maybe 10 to see whether it is a performance or another problem

Comment: Apart from your render settings it depends a lot on what you have in your scene... is this just a defualt cube or a complex scene with many polygons, maybe shader displacement and hair systems etc.? And I don't know if you have a decent GPU to use, but in your render settings you have chosen CPU as device, which is usually a lot slower than GPU Compute.

Comment: Just tried 10 samples and still have the same problem, also I'm making an flag waving using cloth physics with wind on top of an mountain. right now i have 662,325 vertices, 619,464 faces and 1,239,272 triangles. (I don't know if that's a lot or little)

Comment: For cloth it's probably a lot.  Do the cloth sim with lower poly and then you can subdivide after by changing the order of the modifier stack

Comment: Didn't help I'm going to add the blend file soon.

Comment: Also, open the Window::Console prior to rendering and see what the last message is.  Perhaps it's loading one of the large meshes into the render engine, or is it actually saying that it's rendering sample 1 (in the render window)

Comment: "662,325 vertices, 619,464 faces and 1,239,272 triangles" is quite a lot, depending on your machine.   If you run a monitor, is main or video memory maxing out?

Comment: I tried a render with your file.   Cannot do on a 16GB host.  Just loading took 6.6 Gb main memory.  Couldn't even render with Eevee.   Time to trim away at your meshes:  search for reduce memory in this forum.  Things like Edit :: Mesh :: Clean Up :: Decimate.

Comment: 1. Nothing is outputting in the console and the render window is displaying nothing
2. cpu is maxing around 50%, memory around 80% and gpu around 40%
3. I'll try to clean up my meshes

Comment: I think it's the mountains that are causing it and I've managed to clean it up alot to ~200000 each but I'm still not getting anything in the render window. I'll update the blend file to the cleaned up one in a bit.

Comment: Here is a command line render so that you can monitor progress on a command-line console: ```blender -b "NATOPROPAGANDA.blend" -o "//out" -s 1 -e 1 -j 1 -a```

Comment: I get: 
File "<blender_console>", line 1
    blender -b "E:\blender stuff\models\NATOPROPAGANDA.blend" -o "E:\blender stuff\Renders\videos" -s 1 -e 1 -j 1 -a
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 23-24: malformed \N character escape

Comment: hmm. some garbage char between your "blender" and "stuff".  Try hand-typing into a *command* prompt (windows=CMD, linux=bash).   Windows?  Linux?  This command line will also use less memory as -b (background) mode doesn't start up the user graphical interface.  I use these a-plenty in .bat (Windows) or .sh (Linux).  Do not run this in the blender console or the blender script window.